# HTML5 input placeholder that keeps showing (even when typing?)

Tags: css, forms, html, input

It is possible to do something like the screenshot below? The input is of type number, and the "px" is automatically added by the input itself (and cannot be changed).

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want the '0 px' to keep showing even when you're typing in that very text bar?

Comment: Is it ok for you to get `placeholder` in `JQuery` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could overlay your input with a `span` element that has the text `px` at the right.

Comment: @Andy Thanks, too lazy to do it myself.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a placeholder.  Placeholders are only there to indicate to the user what input type is expected.

You could:

1. Use JS to check user value and add "px" to the string,
2. Create a small vector image of 'px' and set as the textbox background positioned right.

Answer (score 1):

you can get value of input by document.getElementById and then add 'px' to the value. finally you can set that value in input.